# User level thread

Tags: c

I am trying to create user level thread. Here is a sample of my code. Can any body help me what is the problem in this program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ucontext.h>

int thread_counter = 0;
int thread1, thread2;
int who_am_i;

struct TCB {
    ucontext_t context;
    void (* fun_ptr)();
};
struct TCB tcb[3];
char stack[2][8192];


//----------------------
int thread_create(void (*fun)()) {
    static volatile int s;
    thread_counter++;
    s = 0;
    getcontext(&tcb[thread_counter].context);

    if(!s) {
        tcb[thread_counter].context.uc_stack.ss_sp   = stack[thread_counter];
        tcb[thread_counter].context.uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof(stack[thread_counter]);
        tcb[thread_counter].context.uc_link          = &tcb[0].context;
        tcb[thread_counter].fun_ptr                  = fun;
        s = 1;
    }
    else {
        tcb[who_am_i].fun_ptr();
    }

    return thread_counter;
}


void thread_yield(int next_thread) {
    static volatile int switched;
    switched = 0;
    getcontext(&tcb[who_am_i].context);

    if(!switched) {
        switched = 1;
        who_am_i = next_thread;
        setcontext(&tcb[next_thread].context);
    }
}


//----------------------
void f1() {
    printf("start f1\n");
    thread_yield(thread2);
    printf("finish f1:\n");
}

void f2() {
    printf("start f2\n");
    thread_yield(thread1);
    printf("finish f2\n");
}


//----------------------
int main() {
    thread1 = thread_create(f1);
    thread2 = thread_create(f2);

    who_am_i = 0;
    thread_yield(thread1);
    return 0;
}
```

Thread is not switching properly. When I run it, it gives following output:

```
start f1
start f2
finish f2
```

Thank you

Comment: In the `thread_yield` function, why do you have the `switched` variable made `static`? You set the value to zero on every call anyway. Same with the variable `s` in the `thread_create` function.

Comment: there is no point of using s and swithched in your code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg. Let `static` keyword is removed. But it gives same output.

Comment: @Koushik [Link](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getcontext.2.html). `There is no direct way to detect whether a return from getcontext() is from the first call, or via a setcontext() call. The user has to invent her own bookkeeping device`. Variable `s` and `switched` are used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You have an *undefined behavior* situation.

In `thread_create` you increase `thread_counter` the first thing you do. So when you create the second thread `thread_counter` will be `2`. Then you access `stack[2]` which will give you undefined behavior.

---

You also hardcode the `uc_link` member of the context to `&tcb[0].context`, which is never initialized due to your "premature" increment of `thread_counter`.

But the main problem is that you don't actually *create* a new context, you just get the context for the current thread. You should use [`makecontext`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/makecontext) for each thread instead.

Comment: Thank you Joachim Pileborg. You are right. But even if I changed code `stack[thread_counter]` to `stack[thread_counter - 1]` there is no change in o/p.

Comment: @Ravi Updated my answer with other problems.

Comment: Thank you JoachimPileborg for help, But **1.** I don't understand about what you meant to say by "create context" **2.** `tcb[0].context` will be initialized by default when `thread_yield` called first time **3.** For `makecontext`, we are restricted to use `getcontext` and `setcontext` only as per our requirement.

Comment: @Ravi In that case it's most likely as an old answer, now deleted, that said that the main thread exits before both sub-threads have finished. After yielding to the first thread, the main program should enter a loop and yield to all non-finished threads as long as there are non-finished threads. When all threads have exited first then your main program may exit.